# Prove or disprove that this function is continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

If $f(x,y)$ is a real valued continuous function defined in $A \times B$ where $A$, $B$ are compact sets in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ respectively. Let $g(x)=\min_{y \in B}f(x,y)$. Prove or disprove that $g$ is a continuous function.

Comment: Without further assumption, what prevents the case of $f(x,y)=\varphi(x)$ ($f$ does not depend on $y$ at all) with $\varphi$ not continuous, so that $g=\varphi$ is not continuous?

Comment: $f$ should be continuous. Then $g$ is actually well-defined and continuous.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma , yeah, I missed the condition that f should be continuous. I thought about this for a while but could not figure out the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since f is continuous, for every $x \in A$, there exits $y_x \in B$ such that $g(x)=f(x,y_x)$.

If for some $x_0 \in A$, there exits $\epsilon_0 >0$ and a sequence $x_n \rightarrow x_0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ such that $g(x_0)<g(x_n)-\epsilon_0$, i.e. $f(x_0, y_{x_0})<f(x_n,y_{x_n})-\epsilon_0$.

Now for such $\epsilon_0$, there exits $\delta>0$ such that $|f(a_1,b)-f(a_2,b)|<\epsilon_0/2$ as long as $|a_1-a_2|<\delta$.

Therefore, for n large enough, $|x_n-x_0|<\delta$, and thus $f(x_n,y_{x_n})<f(x_0,y_{x_n})+\epsilon_0/2$, hence $f(x_n,y_{x_n})>f(x_0,y_{x_0})+\epsilon_0>f(x_n,y_{x_0})-\epsilon_0/2+\epsilon_0=f(x_n,y_{x_0})+\epsilon_0/2$, which contradicts the fact that $f(x_n,y_{x_n})=min_{b\in B}f(x_n,b)$.

For the other direction, the method is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Take $A=B=[0,1]$, and $$f\colon(x,y)\in A\times B \mapsto \begin{cases} 1 & x\in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & x\notin\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$ Then $g\colon x\in[0,1] \mapsto \begin{cases} 1 & x\in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & x\notin\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$ as well, and is not continous.

(Did you miss an assumption on $f$? Right now, it's not even clear why in your question $g$ is defined: why would the minimum exist in general?)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I forgot to say f should be continuous. In this case, is g continuous?